# Exporting functions from .NetNative DLL

Tags: c#, dll, dllexport

From what i know writing a DLL in C# that exports C-Style functions that can be loaded from a native application written in a language like C or C++ is not directly possible due to the nature of language (IL, JIT Compiler). The only information incould find about achieving such a thing involved COM or some C++/CLI glue code.

However the official Microsoft Documentation says the following about .NetNative:

> NET Native uses the same back end as the C++ compiler, which is optimized for static precompilation scenarios.

Does this mean writing a native DLL is possible using .Netnative? And if yes, how?

Comment: It is an ahead-of-time compiler, the opposite of just-in-time.  Important for mobile devices that can't afford a framework install and dynamic compilation.  It can only work on the Store server, does not at all do what you want.  Google "unmanaged exports" for another way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean writing a native DLL is possible using .Netnative?

No.  The problem that COM Interop and C++/CLI solve is that there's no way to express a C/C++ compatible function export with C#.   Both of them allow you to do that and to marshal data from .NET types to C/C++ types.

And .NET Native compiles whole apps, not individual libraries.

Comment: Thats sad to hear. This really sounds like something that could be technically supported in the future. It would really make C# more flexible.